# Display S57 ENC chart data in World Wind

Tags: worldwind

I would like to read an s57 ENC data file and display it in my WorldWind application.

Is there any possible way to do same?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct support for S57 ENC data in WorldWind. We managed to get it done (in a fashion) by [using gdal to convert S57 to shapefiles](http://home.gdal.org/projects/s57/). Then you need to use custom layers or renderers to apply the correct styles to the shapefiles.

S57 data includes vector information as well other attributes like depth, or buoy type. The ENC does not include the information required to show little pictures of anchors or radio towers, or even to color the land and sea correctly. That is included in the [IHO ECDIS presentation library](http://www.iho.int/iho_pubs/IHO_Download.htm) (S-52) and will need to be applied separately.

It is a lot of work. Best of luck.